# Protobuf naming conventions

Tags: protocol-buffers

Besides the rather short Google provided [style guide](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/style.html), here are my thoughts on naming Google Protocol Buffer messages.

1. Use "Message" at the end of message types names.

   - This makes it easy to see in source code that a class is a protobuf generated class.  This also has the advantage that if I have a rich domain specific class, then it can have the real name, say AddressBookMessage for the protobuf class and AddressBook for the real class.
2. For Java users, it appears that having `java_outer_classname` end in `Protos` is standard.

   - I didn't notice this initially, so my current protobuf classes are in `com.example.project.protobuf.MyProtos` , but I don't see a reason to keep it there given that we need to have a containing class, so it could be moved to `com.example.protobuf.MyProtos` unless there are no classes in the project's top package.
3. Start enums at 0 to match C/C++.
4. Use a singular name for a repeated field.

   - Most of the generated methods sound better with a singular field name, even if it is repeated, e.g. message->add_child(), instead of message->add_children() if one had a repeated child field.

Are there any other standards people use or differ from these?

Comment: What do you mean by "Start enums at 0 to match C/C++"?

Comment: @bialix, assigning values to the enum members, the Protobuf style page show them starting at 1, see "enum Foo" at http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/style.html.  But I see other examples starting at 0 on other pages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Disclaimer: answer from a Googler using protobufs on a daily basis. I'm by no means representing Google in any way.

1. Don't do that. Compiled protocol buffers are just a class definition specified by the language you are using, with some improvements. Adding "Message" is extra verbosity. Normally you just use protocol buffers without other class definitions, and even if you use other class definitions, just import java_outer_classname and do a dot from that. You can even put full path of a thing in code to erase one line of import, no problem.
2. Although not specified officially, it sounds like a good suggestion, because normally you put more than one proto inside a folder.
3. You normally start with 0. See the protocol buffer language guide.
4. You use plurals for repeated field names. Read the following to get some feeling using it: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial

Comment: Regarding #1, they are a class in the language but they represent a message. It's not extra if it helps differentiate the personMessage from the person data class in a repo a person view model somewhere else etc

Comment: Regarding 4. Using a plural name for a repeated field feels more natural to me. It also matches the current example at https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial ... for example: "repeated PhoneNumber phones = 4;" and "repeated Person people = 1;"

Comment: I agree with #1 and #3. I don't have any experience with Protobuf+Java, therefore I can't judge #2. Note that there exists a guideline for #4 now using plural names for `repeated` fields. Refer to my full answer.

Comment: Your answer does not keep consistent with google protobuf doc. Google protobuf use plural for repeated one.

Answer (score 10):

I don't agree with answer 4. In the linked article I can find only examples like this:

```
repeated PhoneNumber phones = 4;
repeated Person people = 1;
```

And even in https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3 we only find plurals:

```
repeated Result results = 1;
repeated string snippets = 3;
```

Comment: Using a plural field name is redundant, as it is already indicated as `repeated`. For the `results` example you cited, the compiler generates `getResults(int index)` and `getResultsList()` getters, which is awkward and possibly misleading, especially if you're using a dynamic language.

Ideally, the compiler would be intelligent about it, infer the singular form from the plural field name, and generate `getResult(int)` and `getResults()`. But that might also be confusing on its own, and would incur unnecessary computation.

Comment: Google API design guide apparently disagrees with me:

https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/naming_convention#repeated_field_names

Comment: This is the documentation for Google APIs. The protobuf style guide doesn't address repeated field names. I prefer also "always singular", because most of the code generators add Map() or List() suffixes to the properties.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is the **https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/** which talks about protobuf/gRPC design conventions that are used in Google's own APIs.

The protobuf Style Guide (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/style) is rather short as you said.

Comment: The proto specific documentation is https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/proto3 and is even less dense I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Google added a guideline for `repeated` field names (point 4) at https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/style in the meanwhile:

> Use pluralized names for repeated fields.
>
> ```
> repeated string keys = 1;
> ...
> repeated MyMessage accounts = 17;
> ```

It generates **one** bad function name for the `add_<field_name>` member function:

```
// Bad method name.
auto* const newKey = msg.add_keys();
// OK!
auto* const anotherNewKey = msg.mutable_keys()->Add();
// OK!
auto const * const allKeys = msg.keys();
auto const& firstKeys = msg.keys(0);
```

One could argue that the first method is redundant anyway. By using the `mutable_<field_name>` member function I do not see any problems regarding ugly method names if plural field names are used for `repeated` fields.

Therefore I will try to follow this guideline from now on. Another reason for it: We also tend to use plural variable names for containers/collections in C++, e.g.

```
auto keys = std::vector<std::string>{};
```